# Whereas for some applications ..., ... for [other|others]

Tags: word-choice

How should I end this sentence?

- A: Whereas for some applications this is relevant, it has limitations for **other**.
- B: Whereas for some applications this is relevant, it has limitations for **others**.

While I see option A valid as it implies "other applications", I was suggested option B. However, my gut feeling tells me that "for others" is rarely used with things (I directly associate it with people).

How should I think about it?

Comment: The first one is plural, so the parallel second one should be, too.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason why _others_ should not be used for things, if there are several other things!

Comment: This will be less awkward with some rearranging and substitutions, e.g., *Whereas this is relevant for some applications, for others the relevance is more limited.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Other' should really only be singular if it is *describing* 'applications' (to be more specific, when it used as an adjective right before 'applications', as in 'other applications'). Whereas, in this sentence, the word is *replacing* applications. Thus, it must be in the plural form (making Option B the correct form).

If you do want to keep 'other' in its singular form, you can rewrite Option A like so —

> Whereas for some applications this is relevant, it has limitations for other applications.